# How do I get my dropdown menu to allow only one open dropdown at a time, and stay open on click of a <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a dropdown menu that shows the dropdown menu onclick, rather than on hover. This requires js, and it sort of works.

Right now the menu show/hides on click of the item itself. It also hides all open submenus on click outside of the submenu. Both of these are good.

However, there are two bugs that I'm unable to solve elegantly:

1. The submenu hides on click of a child list item, but it should stay open.
2. Multiple submenus can be open at once, but I want all other submenus to close when a new one is opened.

The codepen is here: http://codepen.io/dr-potato/pen/rLleC?editors=111

What would be the simplest, most elegant and robust way to create this kind of menu with JS?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="Navigation-listItem is-dropdown">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <ul class="Navigation-list is-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="Navigation-listItem is-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul class="Navigation-list is-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.Navigation-list {
    display: block;
}

.Navigation-list.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Navigation-listItem').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').toggleClass('is-hidden');
    });
});

/* Anything that gets to the document
   will hide the dropdown */
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".Navigation-list.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
$(".Navigation-listItem.is-dropdown").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your click event to hide all submenus then show those under the current item, instead of toggling:

```
$('.Navigation-listItem').click(function() {
      $(".Navigation-list.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');
      $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').removeClass('is-hidden');
});
```

[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hoKAB)

**Edit**

Sorry, missed the need to toggle if you clicked the open element.  One option is to hide all submenus then show the one wanted as before, but check first if it was already open, in which case we just hide it.  Then add an event to the sub menus to stop propagation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Navigation-listItem').click(function(e) {
      if( $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').hasClass('is-hidden') ){
        $(".Navigation-list.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');
        $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').removeClass('is-hidden'); 
      } else {
        $(".Navigation-list.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');         
      }          
    });
  $('.Navigation-listItem .Navigation-list.is-dropdown').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

An alternative would be to check via `e.target` what was clicked.

I have updated the codepen

Comment: Cool! Do you know how to prevent it from closing when a dropdown <li>-item (or any other descendants of the dropdown list) is clicked?

Comment: Also, it isn't closing anymore when the link is clicked again because it doesn't toggle anylonger.

Comment: Something like $.not(this) to select everything but the clicked element, hide those, and toggle the class for the clicked element. But I can't get that to work..

Comment: You could do that but you would need to handle the clicks on sub menus as well - they propagate up.  See my edit for one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

css

```
.Navigation-list {
 display: none;
}
.is-dropdown{
 display:block;
}
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.Navigation-listItem').click(function() {
  $('.is-dropdown').removeClass('is-dropdown');
  $(this).children('.Navigation-list').addClass('is-dropdown');
 });
});
```

[Pen](http://cdpn.io/rLleC)